# Upgrade as if fresh install

Tags: 11.04, 12.04, upgrade

I made an old desktop operational again, but I want to have a new username, and get rid of everything in the present natty installation. Is it possible to upgrade to 12.04 as if performing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you want to do is a full install not an upgrade. Choose "Erase Ubuntu" rather than "Install beside" in the partitioning section of the installer and you will have a fresh desktop you seek.

Comment: After backing up any data and preferred settings ..